# Создание криптоконтейнера с одноразовым паролем

Tags: безопасность, криптография, шифрование

Возникла необходимость создания криптоконтейнера для расшифровки которого нужно использовать пароль , который будет меняться каждые 60 секунд. Нельзя перезаписывать криптоконтейнер. Нельзя дешифровть криптоконтейнер старыми ключами.
Нужно придумать алгоритм действий для выполнения этих требований. Система с точки зрения пользователя напоминает Google authenticator , но только не для двухфакторной аутентификации , а для дешифрования криптоконтейнера. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Это невозможно.

Comment: Все возможно (.         )

Comment: можно попробовать через электронный генератор частиц

Answer (score 1):

Я нуб в криптографии, но что если сделат так:

1. Генерируем рандомный ключ
2. Шифруем то что нужно рандомным ключом
3. Шифруем рандомный ключ временным ключом
4. Перешифровываем временный ключ раз в 60 секунд